# Lebesgue Iterated integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to evaluate this integral:

$$\int_A\int_B1_{x\neq y} \, d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y)$$

where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I think the answer should be $\mu(A)\mu(B)$ but I'm not sure how to prove or disprove it. What is the value of this integral?

Comment: That depends on what $\mu$ is. If $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure you can figure this out from Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: The definition of $\displaystyle \int_A\int_B 1_{x\neq y} \, d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y)$ and that of $\displaystyle \int_{A\times B} 1_{x\neq y} \, d(\mu\times\mu)(x,y)$ are not exactly the same.  The first is an iterated integral and the second is a double integral.  Their values agree if the double integral of the absolute value of the function being integrated is finite.  That's Fubini's theorem. Your title says "double integral".  $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy for the function $1_{x\neq y}$, they do agree

Comment: $\ldots\,$ I should add that the values also agree in all cases where the function being integrated is non-negative, regardless of whether the value of the double integral is finite.  That's Tonelli's theorem, and it is applicable to this case.  But still one should be aware that the definitions differ. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the insight. I'll definitely stay on the look for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $A$ and $B$ have finite measure, the set $E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x\ne y\}$ has measure $\mu(A)\mu(B)$, as $E^c$ is a subset of the image of $\mathbb R$ under the Lipschitz map $x\mapsto (x,x)$ and therefore has measure zero. It follows then that
$$\iint_{A\times B}\chi_E(x,y)\ \mathsf d\mu_2(x\times y) = \mu_2(A\times B)=\mu(A)\mu(B). $$
Since $\chi_E$ is nonnegative and $\mu_2$-measurable (where $\mu_2$ denotes $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure), Tonelli's theorem yields
$$\iint_{A\times B}\chi_E(x,y)\ \mathsf d\mu_2(x\times y)=\int_A\int_B\chi_E(x,y)\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx=\int_B\int_A\chi_E(x,y)\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy.$$

Comment: Assuming that $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, yes. Although there are ways of doing this that seem simpler to me...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Just being precise!

Comment: Very helpful and gives great insight. Thank you.

Comment: My comment wasn't about being precise. There's no reason you need the stuff about the diagonal having measure zero because something's Lipschtiz - you can just evaluate the integral as is using Tonelli. Seems simpler

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Certainly true, I just find it helpful for my own understanding to evaluate a double integral directly when it is feasible.

Comment: Huh? The idea that it's preferable to evaluate it directly was exactly my point! Look: For every $y$, $\int_B\chi_E(x,y)dx = \mu(B\setminus \{y\})=\mu(B)$. So now you have $\int_{A}\mu(B)dy=\mu(A)\mu(B)$. That's simpler than invoking the thing about that map being Lipschitz. Also, considering that the OP is asking the question, it seems much more likely to be an answer using only things he knows.